# TFS 2010 merge by file type

Tags: tfs

How can one merge by file type? The following is not a legitimate command:
`tf merge /recursive /baseless $/source/*.cpp $/destination`

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I need a 2nd merge on a root folder for certain files only since they were not merged (target kept)

Answer (score 0):

Merges can be done at the file and folder level. There is no way to merge with a filter of file type.